# filter_var in php 5.3.8

Tags: php

I am developing a user registration form and want to validate a user's email address.
However,all the php docs I have read suggest the use of filter_var.
My script validates a valid email as invalid.
Please post a working script or perhaps guide me through my script.
Hers is my script :

```
     <?php
      if(isset($_POST['email'])== true && empty($_POST['email'])false)
      {
       $email = $_POST['email'];
      }
      if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
      {
       echo"valid email";
      }
      else
      {
      echo"invalid email";
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to filter\_var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653537/alternative-to-filter-var)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])== true && empty($_POST['email'])false)
```

this should be

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) )
```

or as [@jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) you can use just

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
```

the `empty()` does implicit `isset()`

Comment: Or just `if (!empty($_POST['email']))`

Comment: @Jack i think i would show error ... undefined email if email not set

Comment: Nope, empty() does implicit isset()

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
echo(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? "valid email" : "invalid email");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(isset($_POST['email'])== true && empty($_POST['email'])false)
                           ^^^^^^^--redundant               ^^^^^---typo?
```

Comment: The whole line is redundant, because OP should use `filter_input` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you shouldn't use `filter_var`, but [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/filter_input). This is all the code you would need:

```
if ($email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // email was submitted and is a valid email
}
```

This [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55478) might be related to your problem though.