# Alternative to filter_var

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [filter_var in php 5.3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648117/filter-var-in-php-5-3-8)

I recently upgraded to php 5.3.8 and I am having problem validating an email address a user enters into a registration form using "filter_var".
I want to ensure that when a valid email address is entered I post it to a database and if for some reason the format of the email address is incorrect I inform the user to enter a valid email address. 
So I checked php.net and it turns out filter_var does not exist in php 5.3.8
Does anyone know of an alternative to filter_var in php 5.3.8

Comment: I see nothing that says `filter_var` doesn't exist in PHP 5.3.8.  Can you provide a link to where you read this?  The official documentation says it's available in PHP >=5.2.0

Comment: You would get a fatal error, not an "invalid" email address. Chances are you misinterpret the allowed syntax. How does that address look? -- If the filter ext should really be compiled out, you could use [upgradephp](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/) providing a limited userland implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about the provided email address being syntactically valid, e.g. RFC 2822-compliant, then this regex will serve:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: I haven't verified this, and I'm just playing devil's advocate here, but I highly doubt this regex is 100% RFC compliant for checking email syntax.  If it were, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` would probably already use it, and there wouldn't be 50 million different regexes floating around the internet attempting to do the same thing to varying degrees of success ([`Mail::RFC822`](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) uses a much longer one, for example).

Comment: The link to the site is http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=filter_var++%28PHP+5+%3E%3D+5.3.8&scope=quickref

Answer (score 0):

> ## filter_var
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)
>
> filter_var — Filters a variable with a specified filter

The docs say it exists just fine in 5.3.8, so you should be able to just use it...